# Как получить раскладку по 2 полям SQL

Tags: sql

Данные о клиентах хранятся в таблице member следующей структуры:

```
Поле                      Описание
member_id                 Уникальный идентификатор клиента
member_last_name          Фамилия
member_first_name         Имя
member_patronymic         Отчество
member_sex                Пол (1-м, 0 - ж)
member_birthday           дата рождения (необязательное поле, может быть null)
```

Написать запрос, выдающий раскладку клиентов по годам рождения и полу:

```
Год рождения         Пол         Кол-во клиентов в базе
1980                 Ж           120
1980                 М           150
1981                 Ж           220
1981                 М           350
```

Comment: Ничем не отличается от получения количеств по одному полю, просто указать в group by два поля. А вы что сами пробовали сделать перед тем как задать вопрос ?

Comment: @Mike Такое ощущение, что сюда повадились ленивые студенты, которым всё равно на результат, лиш бы препод отстал.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT year(`member_birthday`), `member_sex`, COUNT(`member_sex`) FROM members GROUP BY year(`member_birthday`), `member_sex` WHERE `member_birthday`
```